# Tracking Clicks; Performance Implications to Searching the DOM

Tags: javascript, dom, mobile, dom-events

I have a Javascript plugin that searches the DOM for any elements starting with the class name "tracking" and adds a click event listener (or another type of listener, if specified) to that element.  The idea is that every time that event occurs on that element, that it runs a Javascript function that sends data to our traffic servers.  Here's what the code looks like:

```
// Once the page is completed loaded
window.mmload(function() {      
    // Get the container object
    obj = document.getElementById(name);

    if ( obj.length < 0 )
        throw ("The Id passed into the tracker does not exist ("+name+")");

    // Find all the elements belonging to the tracking class 
    var trackingClass = new RegExp( /tracking\[[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-_]+\]/g );
    var myElements = getElementsByRegex( trackingClass, obj );

    //For each of those elements...
    for( var i in myElements ) {
        var elm = myElements[i];
        var method = elm.className.match( /tracking\[[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-_]+\]/ )[0].split('[')[1].replace(']','').split('.')[2];
        method = typeof( method ) == 'undefined' ? 'click' : method;

        // Add a click event listener
        myElements[i].addEventListener( method, function(e){
            // Get the element, the link (if any), and the args of the event                
            var link = elm.getAttribute('href') == null ? "" : elm.getAttribute('href');
            var args = elm.className.match( /tracking\[[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-_]+\]/ )[0].split('[')[1].replace(']','').split('.');

            // If a link existed, pause it, for now
            if ( link != '' )
                e.preventDefault();

            // Track the event
            eventTracker( args[0], args[1], ( method == 'click' ? 'redirect' : 'default' ), link );

            return false;
        }, true);
    }
});
```

Right now I've got this chuck of code running once the window has completely loaded (`window.mmload()` is a function I made for appending `window.onload` events).  However, there maybe times when I need to run this function again because I added new elements to the DOM via Javascript with this class name and I want to track them too.

My initial solution was to run this function using `setInterval` to check the DOM every few milliseconds or second or whatever makes the most sense.  However, I was worried if I took this approach that it might slow down the website, especially since this is running on a mobile website for smartphones.  I'm not sure what kind of a performance hit I might take if I'm searching to DOM every so often.

The other approach I had in mind was to simply call the function after adding traceable elements to the DOM.  This is probably the most efficient way of handling it.  However, the people that I'm working with, granted very smart individuals, are Web Designers who don't often think about nor understand very well code.  So the simpler I can make this, the better.  That's why I liked the `setInterval` approach because nothing additional would be required of them.  But if it noticeably slows down the site, I might have to take the other approach.

Comment: Not really an answer, but this seems like EXACTLY what jQuery was designed to help you do.  Using jQuery, your code above would be about 5-10 lines.  Don't be a masochist!  http://jquery.com/

Comment: Actually, at first I did make this in jQuery and then my boss told me to convert it to pure JavaScript.  I think he wanted to keep it simple without having to load any additional libraries.  But yea, I'm with you, jQuery would be easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider **even delegation**.

You just add **one** event listener to the document root and check the class of the element the event originated from (`event.target`). If you want to include also clicks from descendants, you'd have to traverse the DOM up form the target and check whether any of the ancestors contains the class.

I see two main advantages:

- It works for newly generated elements without any extra steps (so the other developers don't have to do anything special).
- It adds only *one* event handler instead of potentially many, which saves memory.

Disadvantages:

- If other event handlers are registered along the path and they prevent the event from bubbling up, you cannot register this event.

**A bit more information:**

An event handler gets an `event` object as first argument. This object has [several properties](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html), among others, [which element the event originated form](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html#target).

E.g. to get the target element:

```
var element = event.target || event.srcElement;
```

This will be a DOM element and you can access the classes via `element.className`.

So your event listener could look like this (note that [IE uses another method to attach event listeners](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_advanced.html) and the event object is not passed but available via `window.event`):

```
function handler(event) {
    event = event || window.event;
    var target = event.target || event.srcElement;
    if(target.className.match(/tracking\[[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-_]+\]/g) {
        // do your stuff
    }
}

if(document.addEventListener) {
   document.addEventListener('click', handler, false);
}
else {
   document.attachEvent('onclick', handler);
}
```

But as I said, this would miss events that are prevented from bubbling up. At least in the browsers following the W3C model (so not IE), you can handle the events in the [*capture phase*](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html) by setting the last parameter to `true`:

```
document.addEventListener('click', handler, true);
```

Comment: Thats an interesting approach.  So I would write like body.addEventListener( method, function(e){ ...}, true); ?  How would I find out which element was clicked on so I can read the class name and find out if it needs to be tracked?

Comment: I only need to track clicks on the "tracking" elements

Comment: This is really helpful and a lot better than attaching event listeners to each individual element.  Thanks!  I'll go with this approach.

Answer (score 0):

If you can live without IE, then there is a `change` event which you can hook into for the window/document/dom element. Simply hook into the event at the document level, and it'd fire anytime something's changed in the page (stuff inserted, deleted, changed). I believe the event's context contains what got changed, so it should be fairly trivial to find any new trackable elements and attach your spy code to it.

Comment: I like that idea!  Then this function would only fire when the DOM is changed instead of all the time.  Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 0):

A third option would be to write a method for manipulating the innerHTML of an element.  At the end of that method simply call your function that refreshes everything.

example:

```
var setHtml = function(element, newHtml){
     element.innerhtml = newHtml;
     yourRefreshFunction();
}
```

So obviously this requires that you have your web developers user this method to update the dom.  And you'll have to do it for anything that is more complicated than simple html edits.  But that gives you the idea.

Hope that helps!